# What is curl command syntax for device_token registration on Urban Airship?

Tags: curl, urbanairship.com

I have an android device_token that i receive from GCM. I want to send it with the curl protocol to Urban Airship and to receive their APID for my android device. I look for something like:

curl -X PUT -u "myAppKey:secretKey" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Basic : xxxxx"
        https://go.urbanairship.com/api/device_tokens/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Urban API for such request. It is possible to receive the APID only with Urban SDK in the application build.